# The chacon transform

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I am following this document http://www.jstor.org/stable/2037431?seq=4

Shouldn't it be necessary to check that the chacon transform is ergodic?  The theorem I'm familiar is this:

Let $T$ be a bijective measure preserving transform on a probability space.  Then $T$ is weak mixing if and only if the induced operator $U$ on $L^2$ (Complex $L^2$) has point spectrum consisting exactly of the point $1$ with each eigenvector for $1$ being the constant class.

I see that they have verified that the only eigenvalue is $1$, and I think I understand it although some details need to be hammered out in my head.  But where have they checked that $1$ only has constant eigenvectors?  In other words, where have they checked that this $T$ is ergodic?  If they haven't checked this, can someone prove it please?

I should say that I always use $T$ to denote the measure preserving transform in question, even though they have used $\sigma$ for this.

As an extra curiosity, I wonder if the theorem I know characterizing weak mixing in terms of complex $L^2$ can also be generalized to situations where $T$ is not a bijective measure preserving transform.

Edit: Actually I no longer think I understand the details surrounding the section on the 4th page where the document constructs an $\alpha$ such that on 3/4 of some interval, one has an approximation.  I don't get why such an $\alpha$ must exist, so if someone could pick up the argument from there that would be helpful too.  Answers to any subset of my 3 questions are appreciated.

Edit: I see, I only get free access because I'm at a university.  Okay, here's a self-contained subquestion that might give me enough of a push to get going on two of the questions.  I'd still have the question about generalizing

"Let $T$ be a bijective measure preserving transform on a probability space.  Then $T$ is weak mixing if and only if the induced operator $U$ on $L^2$ (Complex $L^2$) has point spectrum consisting exactly of the point $1$ with each eigenvector for $1$ being the constant class."

to nonbijective mpts, but that's self contained.

How do I show this: Let $f \in L^2[0, 1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and lebesgue measure.  Then there exists $\alpha\neq0$ so that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $k, n \geq 0$ with $k<3^{(n+1)}$ such that there exists a borel $J \subset [k/3^{(n+1)}, (k+1)/3^{(n+1)})$ with $|J| \leq min(1, \epsilon)/(8*3^{(n+1)})$ and on $[k/3^{(n+1)}, (k+1)/3^{(n+1)}) - J$ we have $|f-\alpha|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. Indicating an off-site link to a (not fully accessible) paper is not a solution.

Comment: I am going to need to start asking nonself-contained questions because I'm starting to learn fairly specialized material out of specific textbooks that may not be part of common knowledge, the way that elementary questions tend to be.  Is there a better website out there where I can ask such questions?  Questions of the form "in so and so textbook, the author says this in the proof of such and such a theorem, but I don't believe him or don't see why it's true.  Please help."  Even when I do ask sufficiently elementary questions, I sometimes want to follow a specific proof, as in here.

Comment: This kind of question is dealt with in the howtoask page of the site.

Comment: Weakly mixing $\implies$ ergodic. But I'm lost with your question.

Answer (score 1):

The author omitted the proof that the transformation is ergodic.  It is a rank-one cutting and stacking transformation which is always ergodic.  Possibly, the proof is in one of the two references.  It is not difficult to prove.